# How to create dynamic grid based on Dropdown value selection

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

In wpf application I have tab which has Dropdown . Dropdown has list of different tables. All tables has different columns. I want to achieve following functionalists,

1) Based on Dropdown selection display a grid with all columns for selected table.
2) Add a new row to that table
3) Edit a columns for selected table

I'm new to WPF and it will be really great if anyone could suggest me what should be the good approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using MVVM:
1. Bind the combobox selectedItem to a property as below:

```
public int SelectedItem
{
    get 
    { 
        return _selecteditem; 
    }
    set 
    {
        if (_selectedItem != value)
        {
             _selectedItem = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
             UpdateGridData(); 
        }
    }
}
```

When selection changes the UpdateGridData method is called. Update the collection  which binds to the data grid ItemsSource in the UpdateGridData method.

eg: let your DataGrid be bound to a collection called MyCustomCollection which is declared as below:

```
public ICollectionView MyCustomCollection
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

your XAML will look as below:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCustomCollection}" .../>
```

In your view model implement the UpdateGridData() as below:

```
void UpdateGridData()
{
//resultfromDatabase is the collection from which the data based on the selected item is added to
   var resultDataFromDatabase = GetDataFromDatabase(this.SelectedItem);
   MyCustomCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(resultDataFromDatabase);
}
```

2. To add a new row simply call the Add() method of the source for the collection to which you are binding the DataGrid ItemsSource. You should also look at CanUserAddRows property of the datagrid.
3. To edit datagrid make the simply grid editable ans save data when focus changes. Or you can create a DataGridTemplateColumn in the DataGrid and add a custom edit button within it which can enable edit of the row or open a new modal window where you can edit fields and save it.

Hope this helps.

---

Please don't forget to vote if the answer has helped and mark as answer if this answered your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Yes I'm using MVVM. With this approach how should be the view ? Shall I create DataGrid with AutoGenerateColumns="True"?

Comment: No. You dont have to AutoGenerateColumns unless you are adding new columns to the Collection. I assume you need to add rows and not columns. Additionally when you are creating DataGridTemplateColumn to edit through modal window, you will have to do this through XAML preferably.

  *<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Edit"/>
 </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>*

Comment: Yes, I want add rows to grid once selected table is displayed. May be I forgot to mention that all this tables in dropdown has around 100 rows (max) in database. So once i select anytable from dropdown it should display all the values from database and then I should be able to edit and add new rows to it. So it's pretty much clear what you said but I'm confused about how should be the view ? As every table has different columns

Comment: Since every table has different columns you will have to set AutoGenerateColumns to true. Simply bind your DataGrid's ItemsSource to a collection in view model and every time the combobox selection changes update this collection with the new data retrieved from database. You may want to consider enabling scrolling or paging considering you have several rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this approach. Also is there any approach in which we can hide a views and display desired view based on dropdown selection? So in this approach we will have different views/viewModel for each table in dropdown.

Comment: I would rather suggest you not hide views as when you initialize the control all the views are loaded. You can load a single datagrid and update its ItemsSource based on dropdown selection and set the visibility of this datagrid to Visible only if an item is selected. If you wish to load different views for every selection change, then the best approach would be to proceed ViewModel first design using data templates. This way when you set CurrentViewModel to ABCViewModel only the ABCView which is associated to this view model will be made visible. This means you load view only when needed.

Comment: Again thanks a lot for your quick response. When you say "Simply bind your DataGrid's ItemsSource to a collection in view model ". My question was how can we bind different collection to same datagrid item source. Example, my first table is of type table1 and second table of table2 etc. So collection would be different depending on dropdwon selection.How to define a grid in this case?

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed description. Just started implementing it.

Comment: Nothing is displayed when with this approach. I changed MyCustomCollection type to table type and it worked.          public ObservableCollection<ILookupConversionTrigger> CustomCollection
       {
           get; set;
      }                                                                    and initilized custom collection in constructor as  CustomCollection = new ObservableCollection<ILookupConversionTrigger>();

Comment: But this will work only for one table. So to display dynamic views I want to use your method. Do i need to initialize it?